# Design Issue - Launching new Fragment from TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I'm not quite sure if there's a "best way" to tackle the following design issue.

I have a Tablayout with 2 Tabs in my MainActivity. Each Tab is a different Fragment. I go to Tab1 and see Fragment1. I need to launch a new Fragment (1A) from Fragment 1 and am not sure the best way to do it? I was thinking about one of these.

A) Take the Tabs out of my MainActivity and place them in a separate MainFragment, which gets launched with the app. That way when the user launches Fragment 1A, it replaces just the 1 MainFragment with the Tabs.

or

B) Keep the Tabs in the MainActivity and find a way to replace Fragment 1 with Fragment 1A when under Tab1.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't do both of points... Frag1 visible under Tab1 should contain all the layout (including initialy hidden) and logic for this view. If you need to show smth new it may be smaller (then popup, dialog etc.) or expand some layout, maybe with some animation (you may still use `ViewPager` inside `Fragment` inside `ViewPager`, disable touch events and manipulate scrolling programmatically...).

When Action picked by user is intended to show smth *so-much-improtant* that previous screen is not needed at all then you should probably open new `Activity`

PS. If you insist to replace current "screen" (in fact `Activity`s content) note that title of Tab1 may not representing what contains Frag1A. It very depends what kind of content you have there. You may consider move `TabLayout`/`RecyclerView` to e.g. `FrameLayout` container and add to it you Frag1A covering whole previous view including Tabs. In current design guidelines you can even find suggested solution for way of showing new fragment - with circular reveal animation

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand very well what you want, but possibly this.

Use FragmentPagerAdapter..

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private static final int NUM_TABS = 3;

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            return Tab1Fragment.newInstance();
        case 1:
            return Tab2Fragment.newInstance();
        default:
            return Tab3Fragment.newInstance();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_TABS;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    if (position == 0){
        return "Tab 1";
    }

    if (position == 1){
        return "Tab 2";
    }

    return "Tab 3";
}
```

In your activity...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Tabs
    TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    TabsPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);
}
```

Comment: My question is, using your answer, If I go to Tab 1 and now would like to launch a new Fragment from there, how would I do that? For example Tab 1 contains a recyclerView of names and  a FAB to add a new name. I click the FAB to add a new name and would like to be taken to another Fragment to input this information. How would I add this other Fragment?

Comment: FAB is _very_ intended to open new `Activity` as it should pointing on a very important functionality of your app

Comment: Ahh okk, so **snachmsm**  answers your question. You can call other Activity/Fragment with only field, and return this value to you Fragment..

Comment: Ok then maybe you can help me pick the best route....Let's say I need to add a new name in Fragment 1, my thought process is to launch a new something to get that data(Fragment,AlertDialogue,Activity)---> enter the info there-->save to database via Content Provider-->Close screen and return to Fragment 1 where Loader repopulates the RecyclerView. My initial thought was to have a FAB exist in Fragment 1. My question now is, where do I go from here? Should I launch a whole new Activity to get the name input? It logically makes sense but was wondering if it's best practice? Thank you.

Comment: FAB is indicated to "small action", example: You will show other fragment/activity in fullscreen when you click in FAB(Floating Action Bar), but according to **Material Design** you do not usually return to the previous state of vision after show click FAB... 

[Material Design - Find Full screen](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-transitions "Material")

Then you not should use FAB, i belive.